# How to set folder write permission on Azure Web App?

Tags: asp.net, azure

I have hosted one web application on Azure Web application and application have one folder that contains dynamic images means application generated some images and stores on that folder but without write permission I can not save images dynamically please help me

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder in `d:/home/site/wwwroot` and write there.